# blockquote prependTo

Tags: jquery, syntax, prepend

Edit:

This is conflicting when I try @NiftyDude's addition.

Most pages:

```
 $("blockquote").appendTo(".entry");

   <div class="entry">
      <div class="project">
     <blockquote>  </blockquote>    
      </div>

  </div>
```

Which moves the blockquote outside to the entry div.

```
  <div class="entry">
      <div class="project">

      </div>

<blockquote>  </blockquote> 
  </div>
```

The DOM is affecting the outlet page as the blockquote is being appended to the Entry. I want to move it back to the project outlet div.

```
   <div class="entry outlet">
      <div class="project outlet">

      </div>
    <blockquote>  </blockquote>
  </div>
```

to this:

```
       <div class="entry outlet">
      <div class="project outlet">

              <blockquote>  </blockquote>

      </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, `blockquote` isn't the child of `.project`

I think the following is what you are looking for:

```
$(".project.outlet").next("blockquote").prependTo(".project");
```

It looks to me you would like to move each `blockquote` back, so let's try the following:

```
$('blockquote').each(function() {
   if($(this).prev('.project.outlet').length) {
      $(this).appendTo($(this).prev());
   }
});
```

Comment: @uriah is that the newest markup in your question? You have a stray `</div>`, is that a typo?

Comment: Thanks @NiftyDude. I just realised that I have something else moving the blockquotes. The `.entry` must be moving the BQ I need a if this class do this, if this class do that.

Comment: @uriah Sorry I'm having a hard time trying to understand your requirement.. could you edit your question to be more elaborative?

Comment: I hope that helps. The first append script is affecting everything sitewide. I'd like to hook into the `.entry outlet` and move the `BQ` back.